# Подскажите библиотеку для рисования графики в С++

Tags: c++

У меня появилось желание изучить какую-то библиотеку для рисования графики для С++ (самой примитивной 2D графики). Основные требования : простота освоения с нуля , наличие определенного количества туториалов на русском , возможность использования под Code Blocks или DevCpp (компилятор GNU GCC и не очень хочется переходить на что-то новое). Прошу по возможности бросать не только название но и линки на информацию . Заранее Спасибо .

Comment: эмм..а разве CodeBlocks или DevCpp какие-то особенные продукты, чтобы с ними нельзя было использовать какие-то библиотеки? Или для них каждая библиотека подключается своим ни на что не похожим способом? Скорее всего нет

Comment: DreamChild , я не особо разбираюсь в этом поэтому уточнил на всякий случай .

Comment: А что вы понимаете под графической библиотекой? Библиотека для рисования графики? Или библиотека для GUI интерфейса?

Comment: @zenden2k , для рисования графики

Comment: для рисования разных вещей могут разные инструменты использоваться. Можно пару характерных примеров добавить, чтобы меньше от вкуса ответ зависил, [вот из gnuplot галерии можно выбрать](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_cvs/) (если о таких графиках речь идёт).

Answer (score 2):

Если имеется ввиду GUI, тогда [Qt](http://www.qt.io/developers/). Документации море, в том числе и на русском.
Для 2D графики есть [Cairo](http://cairographics.org). Как с документацией на русском - я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Если 3D - я бы посмотрел https://www.unrealengine.com/
исходники теперь открыты, бесплатно (пока игра не принесла $3000)
https://www.unrealengine.com/blog/ue4-is-free
большие игры и инди используют
https://www.unrealengine.com/showcase
кросс-платформенный.

Если 2D - я бы глянул в сторону Cocos2D-X
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/
открытые исходники, MIT лицензия
большое кол-во игр на нем
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/games
кросс-платформенный.

Answer (score 0):

SDL2 наверное+opengl(опционально), если в этом плане 2д

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cairographics.org/ Cairo is a 2D graphics library

---

https://code.google.com/p/skia/

---

http://www.juce.com/

---

http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, в вопросах рисования простой графики [GD библиотека](http://libgd.github.io/) стандарт де-факто.